# A long time ago, on a specific day of the week

Tags: story-identification, movie

There's a gag I've seen at the start of a movie or TV show where there is text overlaid on the screen that says something like "1,000,000 BC", then a second overlay appears that indicates "Saturday".  :)

I don't remember the exact date, (It was something imprecise "BC") it might have been something much smaller like 10 BC, or it might have been written out in words "one million BC", I have no idea.  I also don't remember the exact day of the week that was used in the gag, could have been Wednesday or any other day of the week, but it was definitely a weekday name, I have no idea again which one.  But you get the idea: the gag that a very imprecise year was used along with a very precise day-of-week reference.

I fully expect this gag may actually be used in multiple movies, but I do remember it being a fairly popular show.  I can't even remember if the one I saw was Monty Python or The Simpsons, or a Jack Black movie or what but I'm certain (because it was a gag) that it had a comedic vibe.  Honestly I can't even remember for certain if it happened at the start of the movie (although I'm fairly confident it was) or immediately after a time-travel moment or flash-back in the middle of an episode.

Sorry my memory is completely lacking on this one!  But I'm trying to remember the film/show where I saw this gag being used.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you looking for a particular occurrence of this?  If so you'll need to be explicit about that, and everything that might pertain.  Note that asking for "any occurrence of" creates a list question, which are off-topic.  You might want to read [ask].

Comment: How long ago did you see this?  I remember something similar in *Caveman* (with Ringo Starr).

Comment: @DavidW, I'm not asking for a list.  I'm just acknowledging that because it's a gag, it may have been used elsewhere, perhaps in a derivative work.  I'm also acknowledging that because of that I realize I may have not offered enough information to pinpoint it.

Comment: It looks like the gag was used in dialog on [QI](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/QI)

Comment: Hmm. Not Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure, nor HIstory of the World, Part I, nor Encino Man

Comment: @ZeissIkon, I'm not confident at all, but I'd say more than 10 years ago.  Could have been 40 years ago!

Comment: @Laurel - That reminds me of the joke about the museum curator who proudly announced that an artifact is 30,005 years old. When he's asked how they can be so accurate, he replies that it was dated by the world's foremost specialist as 30,000 years old, and *that was five years ago*

Comment: I quickly looked at [Caveman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qV9vS-dH1EQ) and I don't think it's actually there.  But that sure felt like the right kind of movie.  It's not at the opening.  If it's in the middle somewhere I missed it.

Comment: This sounds very familiar to me, but I can't place it. Seems very much like a Mel Brooks type of line, but I'm not coming up with anything

Comment: Another pretty similar gag was used in the first episode of the TV adaptation of *Good Omens*, which says that "the Heaven and the Earth were created on Sunday, the 21st of October, 4004 BC, [...] at 9:13 in the morning." ([transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=960&t=37730))

Comment: Any chance this was Mel Brooks' History of the World Part 1? It would have been in the first act if so. Can't immediately look for it though.

Comment: Didn't Spaceballs do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The 1981 Ringo Starr movie [*Caveman*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082146/) does this; the first in-title says "**One zillion B.C.**" and the second says "**October 9<sup>th</sup>**":

[image: dry, dusty valley with sparse trees and a few cavemen foraging; in-title reads "one zillion B.C."]

[image: same valley, slightly zoomed in, in-title now reads "October 9th"]

Comment: I picked this one instead of the *Life of Brian* gag because this is closer to the "one million B.C." referenced in the question, although "Saturday" matches *LoB* better.

Comment: Oddly enough, another Beatle -- George Harrison -- arranged for the financing of Life of Brian because he was such a big Monty Python fan.

Answer (score 39):

As an alternative answer, since I've now managed to scare up some images, if "Saturday" is the more important part than the "million B.C." part then you might be thinking of Monty Python's [*Life of Brian*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/) (1979).  It's possible you've seen both and are confusing the year of *Caveman* with the overly-specific date from *Life of Brian*.

After the introductory scene of the birth of Brian (and incidentally Jesus) the movie skips ahead 33 years to the [Sermon on the Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sermon_on_the_Mount).  As crowds of people are shown arriving the in-titles read successively: "Judea A.D. 33," "Saturday afternoon," "About tea-time."

[image: A crowd of people walk from the left in a desert landscape front of a low, barren hill with other barren hills behind and a dusty sky. The in-title reads "Judea A.D. 33"]

[image: The camera pans to the right, revealing more people climbing a slope to the right. The in-title reads "Saturday afternoon."]

[image: Continuing the pan right, a line of people with camels walk along the top of a ridge. The in-title reads "About tea time."]

Comment: Not the same thing at all. "Saturday, one million years B.C." gets its infinitesimal bit of funniness from the fact that weeks and calendars had not been invented that long ago. I think everybody in 33 A.D. Judea would know if it was Saturday, as the Sabbath was quite a big deal.

Comment: @user14111 is that something the Romans did for us?

Comment: @user14111 That's probably why they added the "About tea time" title; it wasn't there in the earlier script I found online.

Comment: I think you've nailed it!  (LoB pun intended)  You're absolutely right that I conflated the ONE ZILLION B.C. from Caveman with the SATURDAY from Life of Brian.  I'll mark the other as answer but honestly these two answers together fully sorted out my faulty memory.  Amazing job - much appreciated!

Comment: @user25730 :) Quite the contrary. The Romans used an 8 day cycle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nundinae 'The name of the 8-day cycle is based upon the Latin word for "nine" because the Romans tended to count dates inclusively'. We got the 7 day week from the Jews, who (probably) got it from the Babylonians / Chaldeans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week

Comment: @PM2Ring you obviously missed the reference, when is the last time you saw the movie?  It was a joke.  And the Jews got the 7 day week directly from God!

Comment: @MarkRansom Um, I got the reference, hence the smiley. I've been a Monty Python fan since the early 1970s, and first saw LoB in the cinema, back when it was released.

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry, smileys are invisible to me. Seeing LoB in the theater must have been fantastic.

Comment: @MarkRansom It was. :) So was seeing *Holy Grail*. A few years earlier, I got to see half of *And Now For Something Completely Different* at the drive-in. My parents got a bit upset by the *Nudge, Nudge* sketch.

Comment: @user14111 But they *wouldn't* know that it was 33 A.D.  Nobody would use that year numbering system until centuries later.